# How find this system $a^2+b^2=3,a^2+c^2+ac=4,b^2+c^2+\sqrt{3}bc=7$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Find the  this system real solution
$$\begin{cases}
a^2+b^2=3\\
a^2+c^2+ac=4\\
b^2+c^2+\sqrt{3}bc=7
\end{cases}$$

I think that  one can use Geometry to solve this system. Maybe there exist an algebraic method.

$$a^2+b^2=\sqrt{3}^2$$
$$a^2+c^2-2ac\cos{(120°)}=2^2$$
$$b^2+c^2-2bc\cos{150°}=\sqrt{7}$$
and note $$150°+120°+90°=360°$$

This is Mathematics competition of Zhejiang province today.

Comment: If this is a competition, it seems bad form to be asking others for help...

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ positive?

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson,This is not asking other for help.I mean to share problem. in china  competition is can't on line.and this problem is today In the morning
,Now is evening in china!

Comment: Observation: $(\sqrt {3})^{2}+2^{2}=(\sqrt {7})^{2}$.

Comment: Observation: $2ab+bc+\sqrt3ca=4\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming $a,b,c>0$, then as you noted the equalities are just cosine laws for $3$ triangles which form a larger triangle with sides $2,\sqrt3,\sqrt7$, because the angles add up to $2\pi$. That triangle is right, because $4+3=7$, so we can find the lengths analytically if we draw it like this:

[image]

Here we set $A=(0,0)$, $B=\left(0,\sqrt3\right)$ and $C=(2,0)$. The angle $APB$ is right, so $P$ lies on the circle with the center $S_1=\left(0,\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)$ and radius $\frac{\sqrt3}2$. The size of the angle $APC$ is $\frac{2\pi}3$, so $ACX$ is an equilateral triangle and $P$ lies on the circle with the center $S_2=\left(1,-\frac{\sqrt3}3\right)$ and radius $\frac{2\sqrt3}3$.

So if $P=(x,y)$, then
\begin{alignat*}{5}x^2+\left(y-\tfrac{\sqrt3}2\right)^2\ &=\left(\tfrac{\sqrt3}2\right)^2&&=\tfrac34&\ \Longleftrightarrow\ &&0\ &=x^2+y^2-\sqrt3\ y\\
(x-1)^2+\left(y+\tfrac{\sqrt3}3\right)^2\ &=\left(\tfrac{2\sqrt3}3\right)^2&&=\tfrac43&\ \Longleftrightarrow\ &&2x\ &=x^2+y^2+\tfrac{2\sqrt3}3y\end{alignat*}
So $x=\frac12\left(\tfrac{2\sqrt3}3+\sqrt3\right)y=\tfrac{5\sqrt3}6y$ and $0=\left(\tfrac{5\sqrt3}6y\right)^2+y^2-\sqrt3\ y\Longleftrightarrow0=y(111y-36\sqrt3)$, so $y=\frac{12\sqrt3}{37}$ and $x=\frac{30}{37}$, because we want the nonzero solution.

Therefore $a=\sqrt{\left(\frac{30}{37}\right)^2+\left(\frac{12\sqrt3}{37}\right)^2}=\dfrac6{\sqrt{37}}$, $b=\sqrt{\left(\frac{30}{37}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt3-\frac{12\sqrt3}{37}\right)^2}=\dfrac{5\sqrt3}{\sqrt{37}}$ and $c=\sqrt{\left(2-\frac{30}{37}\right)^2+\left(\frac{12\sqrt3}{37}\right)^2}=\dfrac8{\sqrt{37}}$.

---

If you want all real solutions, then it can be solved geometrically too. Just consider different signs before $ac$ and $bc$. For example $-ac=-2ac\cos\frac\pi3$ and $\sqrt3\,bc=-2bc\cos\frac{5\pi}6$. We see that $\frac\pi2+\frac\pi3=\frac{5\pi}6$, so we can draw the following picture:

[image]

The triangle $ACX$ is again equilateral and it can be solved in a similar fashion. This gives $a=\dfrac6{\sqrt{13}}, b=\dfrac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt{13}}, c=\dfrac8{\sqrt{13}}$ and if we negate $a$ we get a solution to the original problem.

Similar configurations can be made for the other $2$ possibilities, but there are no solutions, so these two we found together with their negations are all $4$ real solutions.

Comment: Off-topic: Have you thought on naming your user? Sometimes you post interesting answers and I can just remember you as *the-guy-with-the-ochre-and-quite-subdivided-gravatar*:)

Comment: @chubakueno Thanks, is this better? :)

Comment: LOL!  My memory will now call you [u](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/131872/user2345215)[chu](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/37844/chubakueno)[ma](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/58742/math110)[pan](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/766/pandora) (I wish my historical memory were this good!)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an algebraic solution that yields all the real answers.

Let us introduce the complex numbers:
 $$x=\frac{-b+i a}{\sqrt{3}},\quad y=\frac{2a+c}{4}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}c.$$

The first two equations are equivalent to the statement: $\vert x\vert=\vert y\vert=1$, and the third equation tells us that
$$\vert \sqrt{3} x-2i y\vert^2=\left\vert b+\frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{2} c\right\vert^2
=b^2+c^2+\sqrt{3}bc=7$$
On the other hand, since $\vert x\vert=\vert y\vert=1$ we see that
$\vert \sqrt{3} x-2i y\vert^2=3+4+4\sqrt{3}\,\Re(ix\bar{y})$. Thus, we have
$\Re(ix\bar{y})=0$ that is $x\bar{y}$ is a real number of modulus $1$, or $y=\pm x$.

- If $y=x$, we conclude comparing real parts, and imaginary parts that
  $$b=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}a,\qquad c=-\frac{4}{3}a,$$
  and replacing in the first equation we get $b=\epsilon\sqrt{3/13}$ with $\epsilon\in\{+1,-1\}$, and this yields the couple of solutions:
  $$
  a=-\epsilon\frac{6}{\sqrt{13}},~b=\epsilon\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{13}},~
  c=\epsilon\frac{ 8}{\sqrt{13}},\quad\hbox{with }\epsilon\in\{+1,-1\}$$
- If $y=-x$, we conclude similarly that
  $$b=\frac{5}{2\sqrt{3}}a,\qquad c=\frac{4}{3}a,$$
  and Replacing in the first equation we obtain the second couple of solutions:
  $$
  a= \epsilon\frac{6}{\sqrt{37}},~b=\epsilon\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{37}},~
  c=\epsilon\frac{ 8}{\sqrt{37}},\quad\hbox{with }\epsilon\in\{+1,-1\}$$
  and we are done, with four solutions in total.

Comment: Very nice! +1​​